Plumbing: hot water in cold lines
This is a follow up for this question: Plumbing: hot water in cold pipes - water heater problem?
To summarize, sometimes the cold lines of the whole apartment become very hot, which has been happening since we moved in.

This issue is most noticeable in the morning after a whole night without water usage. Every faucet in the aparment gets almost immediate hot water when the cold side is turned on (much faster than the hot side, which takes a while to get hot in the morning). The cold lines return to normal after the hot water is all let out, which can take up to several minutes.
We have an electric hot water tank made in 2019, located in the lower level of the apartment. There is no thermal expansion tank connected to it.
There does not appear to be any recirculation system installed on the hot water tank or under any sinks that we can see.
The shower cartridge was deemed the prime suspect by a local plumber than came to investigate,  and has since been replaced, but the issue persists.
The only other single handle faucet is in the kitchen. We have its hot water side turned off via the shut off valve under the sink, the issue persists.
We have an LG washing machine, and we do not have a good view of its piping (stacked under the dryer in a tight laundry closet), but clothes do not feel hot when we run cold water only cycles.
We are located in British Columbia, Canada

Can the hot water tank itself cause this issue without a crossover point elsewhere in the unit? Will testing water pressure / installing a thermal expansion tank the next steps to go?
Picture of the hot water tank:

Close up of the piping above the tank:


Heating water does cause a slight increase in the water , which might back up into the cold water line, but should only affect the closest faucet/s.  What do you have the temperature setting on the tank?  130F/140F(medium hot) should be the max temp.

@crip659 The tank body says it's factory configured to 140F, we haven't had anyone adjust it since we moved in, but we don't know if it had been adjusted before.

You have two small white lines coming off the pipes.  Their usual use is a recirculation use/system.  If looking for a pump, the pump can be any where in the line(hidden in a closet).

A recirc crossover could be under a lavatory that is farthest from the hot water tank.

@crip659 unfortunately there is nothing visible I can find going in the direction of the small pipes, but I'll keep that in mind when we have a plumber over.

Installing a pressure relief/stabilization tank is NOT the next thing to do. You must find out how hot water is getting into the cold line, The critical location where cold and hot water must be mixed to prevent scalding is the shower. Is it possible that there is a cold into hot mixing junction to serve the shower?  A hot water tank is ideally supposed to be set at 60 C (140 F) to limit growth of certain bacteria, but you never want the shower or lavatories to be able to deliver water that hot. The shower valve is supposed to be thermostaatically controlled but there are other mixing valves.

@JimStewart We just had the shower faucet cartrige replaced, and we couldn't find any other crossover point in the unit without tearing into the walls. That's why I'm asking whether this problem can happen without crossover, but rather hot water from thermal expansion from the water tank getting carried continuously through the system.

How is the apartment heated? Maybe those small lines go to a heating system?

Expansion of water on heating is a small increase in volume. It could never pump water throughout the piping system. What is that knob device on the cold inlet to the tank?

@JimStewart it's all resistive electric baseboard heating, not using the hot water as far as we can see

@JimStewart Google says the knob is some kind of air relief valve, it looks very much like this: https://www.reddit.com/r/whatisthisthing/comments/mekmk2

How many lavatories in the appt? Perhaps the two small lines are to supply a 1st floor half bath, a "powder room", and have nothing to do with the hot water getting into the cold. To test this turn on the hot tap in the lavatory in  the powder room and feel the small hot pipe over the tank. It should get hot immediately.

@JimStewart The small pipes are indeed in the direction of a powder room and did get hot when the the taps were turned on, thank you for solving that mystery

The knob on the cold water inlet to the water heater might be an automatic shutoff valve that closes when it detects a leaking water heater. However, I do not see any sensor connection (electric wire or gas filled tube) that would signal a leak. There are some automatic leak detecting shutoff valves that do not need an expernal sensor. These are designed to close when the flow rate is above a certain amount as would occur with a catastrophic failure of a water heater tank. One of these designed for a water heater would presumably be adjustable and maybe that slit is an opening to adjust

Ask the plumber if this automatic shutoff valve in the cold inlet to the water heater (if that is indeed what it is) could cause backflow of hot water into the cold line and if so can it be adjusted or replaced. AFIK these "WAGS" valves need to be placed under the water heater and in a drip pan so water can get inside to activate the shutoff. Another possibility is that the knob is a pressure reducing valve and was placed there to protect the water heater from  excessive pressure. However normally these presure reducers are in the cold line before it divides,
